# Bad IF Statement in my python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this piece of code, and everything works fine, and now I am trying to build the IF statement correctly.

I only have one ASCEND function right now, so yea, the IF statement references it for ascend and descend, so ignore that piece. When I typed in "r" as my 'answer', it still ran the rainSortAscend.

Can you help point me in the right direction for the IF statement?

```
answer = ""
print('Do you want the rainfall to be ascending or descending?')
answer = input('Answer with "A" or "D"' + answer)


def rainSortAscend(monthRainfall):
    for number in range(len(monthRainfall)-1,0,-1):
        for i in range(number):
            if monthRainfall[i]>monthRainfall[i+1]:
                temp = monthRainfall[i]
                monthRainfall[i] = monthRainfall[i+1]
                monthRainfall[i+1] = temp


if answer == 'a' or 'A':
    rainSortAscend(monthRainfall)
    print(monthRainfall)
elif answer == 'd' or 'D':
    ranSortAscend(monthRainfall)
else:
    print('Start over and type in the specified "A" or "D" option')
```

Comment: Try `if answer == 'a' or answer == 'A':`

Comment: `if answer == 'a' or 'A'` checks whether answer equals to 'a', or literal 'A', which is always true. you need to use `if answer == 'a' or answer == 'A'` or `if answer in ['a', 'A']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using if `answer=='a' or 'A'`, the `'A'` will always be true which causes `rainSortAscend` function to run everytime. if you want to validate single variable for multiple values. You can write your code as shown below

```
if answer in('a','A'):
    rainSortAscend(monthRainfall)
    print(monthRainfall)
elif answer in('d','D'):
    ranSortAscend(monthRainfall)
else:
    print('Start over and type in the specified "A" or "D" option')
```

Comment: Great, thank you, and your answer and Mathias both worked.

Comment: Great it helped, please accept answer to close the question